# UVA online judge runtime error

Tags: java, runtime-error, java-7

I am receiving a runtime error on problem 10107 on the online judge website. If you do not know, the website doesn't give me the actual cause of the error, or a line number, or anything otherwise it would be easy to solve. Anyways, this is my code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

class Prob2 {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
        Vector<Long> nums = new Vector<Long>();

        while (in.hasNext()){
            nums.add(in.nextLong());
            int size = nums.size();
            int mid = size/2;
            //Prints out the median
            System.out.println(size % 2 == 1 ? nums.get(mid) : (nums.get(mid - 1) + nums.get(mid))/2);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried many things, and read other posts, but no previous solutions worked. I have a different code for a different question which also gave me a runtime error. I'm not sure, but it could be a common problem, so here is the other code (question 446)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Prob1 {

    Prob1(){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numLoops = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < numLoops; i++){
        //while (in.hasNext()){
            //gets the input
            String line = in.nextLine();
            String[] parts = line.split(" ");
            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0], 16);
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[2],16);
            String op = parts[1];


            int tot = num1;
            //Checks operation. Built in decimal operations easier than binary or hex operations
            if (op.contains("+")){
                tot += num2;
            }else if (op.contains("-")){
                tot -= num2;
            }

            //Prints out the result padding the binary to 13 digits because that is how it is in the sample output
            System.out.printf("%s %s %s = %d\n", ("0000000000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(num1)).substring(Integer.toBinaryString(num1).length()), op, ("0000000000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(num2)).substring(Integer.toBinaryString(num2).length()), tot);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Prob1();
    }

}
```

As you can see in the second code, I tried changing it to a while loop, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 3):

So, I believe I found the problem. After running an old file that was working, I changed the name of the class to Main, and it seems to have fixed it

Comment: yeah, according to submission specification it seems that we need to always use a "Main" class https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?id=15&Itemid=30&option=com_content&task=view